# Change plotly hovertext dimensions

Tags: r, plotly, hover

I am using [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) with [r](/questions/tagged/r). I am using `hovertext` but need to change the dimensions of the hovertext box.

Here is my data:

```r
my_data <-
  structure(
    list(
      flood_freq = "none",
      count = 111L,
      acres = 213698L,
      coiids = "632879, 632880, 633192, 633643, 633647, 634220, 634252, 2517005, 2517018, 2630129, 2630149, 2630150, 635379, 632879, 632880, 2517005, 635629, 635631, 2517005, 2517018, 2630129, 2630149, 2630150, 2630203, 2630207, 2630215, 2528971, 2406001, 2719494, 2719503, 2719504, 634220, 2517005, 2517018, 2630149, 2630150, 1423710, 2630203, 2630207, 1472815, 1472823, 2630215, 2528971, 2630207, 2406001, 635796, 635797, 635798, 635799, 635803, 635804, 635862, 635864, 635865, 635867, 635868, 635870, 635871, 635917, 635947, 635948, 635949, 635950, 635984, 635985, 635986, 635987, 635988, 635989, 635990, 635997, 636005, 636008, 636095, 636097, 636099, 636119, 636120, 636121, 637182, 637183, 637184, 637196, 637230, 637232, 637259, 637260, 637473, 637475, 637477, 637479, 2719494, 2719503, 2719504, 637647, 637649, 637652, 637657, 637667, 637821, 637944, 637945, 637946, 637947, 637949, 638073, 638160, 638161, 638216, 638217, 638218"
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA, -1L)
  )
```

I make a [plotly](/questions/tagged/plotly) barplot with the coiids as the `hovertext`.

```r
plotly::plot_ly(
  x = my_data$flood_freq,
  y = my_data$count,
  name = "Flood freq.",
  type = "bar",
  hoverinfo = "text",
  hovertext = paste("coiids: ", my_data$coiids)
)
```

The `hovertext` of my concatenated coiids is long and gets cut off by the screen width.

How can I change the dimensions of the hovertext box to give it a constained width and greater height so that all of the coiids can be read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to wrap your hover text using e.g. `stringr::str_wrap`:

```
library(plotly)

plot_ly(
  x = my_data$flood_freq, y = my_data$count,
  name = "Flood freq.", type = "bar",
  hoverinfo = "text", 
  hovertext = paste("coiids: ", stringr::str_wrap(my_data$coiids, 60))
)
```

[image]